# Replacement part for a buzzer to eliminate beeping

Tags: piezo-buzzer

We recently bought an aroma diffuser. Itʼs operated from a 24V DC wall adapter, but for most of the electronics itʼs dropped to 5V (24V is only needed for the actual diffuser part). It works like charm, except every time you press a button it beeps. Itʼs quite annoying and pretty useless, too, so i decided to remove the buzzer instead of reducing the volume. The buzzer is a small piezo one, but it doesnʼt have any identification numbers on it.

The question is, is it safe to just remove it, or should i add a resistor/capacitor (or just a wire, but i doubt that would be a good idea) in place?

Comment: Safe but tape works well too. They must use cheap switches & that beep is for user feedback as it corrodes.

Comment: There is also a visual feedback, thatʼs why i want to completely eliminate the buzzer instead of reducing its volume. Also, we want to operate it at night near children, and we obviously donʼt want to wake them up ☺

Comment: No problems...... except touch 0V pad somewhere while holding the card to dissipate static while soldering

Comment: in most cases cutting the trace to to the sounder will silence it and not cause any other problems,

Comment: put a dab of poster putty in the beeper's little hole to quiet it by about 30DBs; simple, failsafe, reversible.

Answer (score 1):

Very, very unlikely that removing or cutting the connection to the beeper will cause any problems, but without a schematic we cannot say 100%.

If it's the common 12mm diameter x 10mm tall type it's almost surely magnetic, not piezo.

Best bet is to do it reversibly so that even that (tiny) risk is eliminated.